# Naming LOGSEGMENT in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I'm new to Oracle DBs and I'm creating a table that contains a CLOB field for very large JSON Objects.

I'm requested to name the LOGSEGMENT object of the CLOB column but I haven't found how to do it. For now, I'm just creating a table that has a CLOB column and a constraint to check that the CLOB field is actually a json. How do I name the LOGSEGMENT object?

Comment: `LOGSEGMENT` or `**LOB**SEGMENT`?  (I'm also assuming your constraint is the `IS JSON` constraint.)

Comment: Not sure, that's what I was told, they may be wrong. And yes, that is the constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SQL> create table t1 (c1 clob) lob (c1) store as securefile c1_clob;

Table created.

SQL> select table_name, column_name, segment_name from user_lobs;

TABLE_NAME           COLUMN_NAME          SEGMENT_NAME
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
T1                   C1                   C1_CLOB

SQL>
```

More details at: [LOB_storage_clause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6__I2218765)

[image]

Comment: what is the diference between securefile, basicfile, and not putting this argument (just leaving `lob (c1) store as specific_name`)?

Comment: @sant016 You can find the answer to that here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/adlob/introduction-to-large-objects.html#GUID-67FBC558-69AC-4BCC-80B5-F2961283A4A8 When you do not specify the storage type for the LOB, the behaviour is defined by the value of `db_securefile` parameter: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/refrn/DB_SECUREFILE.html